# How do I find the infinite series of a trig function that's weird?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

The title.

For example:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sin\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$$

How would I go about solving this. Does it converge? Does it diverge? What does it converge to?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Substitute $k = 1/n$. What is the first order expansion of $\sin(k)~$ around $k=0$ (I.e. as $n \to \infty$)?

Answer (score 4):

First, show that

$$\frac{x}{2} \leq \sin(x),\quad {0 \leq x \leq 1}.$$

Now, use this inequality to compare your series with one-half the harmonic series.

Answer (score 4):

The sum diverges. This is not hard to show as for small values of $x$,
$$\sin(x) \approx x$$ and that $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n}= \infty$$

Answer (score 2):

We have $$\lim_n{\sin{1\over n}\over {1\over n}}=1$$ By the [limit comparison test](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_comparison_test) the series $\sum \sin{1\over n}$ is divergent as the series $\sum {1\over n}$ is divergent.